# Multiple dialogs are created when chatting Quickblox

Tags: ios, dialog, quickblox

While creating a chat dialog for a group.
For e.g User A is creating dialog and User B want to use that dialog.
But sometimes scenario is occurring that User A create one dialog and then User B create another dialog.
So they are not able to chat with each other because of two different dialogs.
Below is the code i am using to create dialog :-

```
-(void) moveToChatView:(QBChatDialog *)chatDialog ObjFriend:(Friend *)objFriend

{
    [QBRequest createDialog:chatDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatDialog *createdDialog)

    {
         // Success, do something
    }
    errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response)
    {

    }];
}
```

Edit :- Is there any method like createOrJoinRoomWithName??

Comment: you want Dialogue only for A and B or for group like , A, B ,C ,D ?

Comment: Hi Badal, I want it like A,B,C,D There can be many users. So i want it for a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To if you want to add user in groupchat then you need to update the group dialogue.

```
QBChatDialog *updateDialog = [[QBChatDialog alloc] initWithDialogID:@"53aac645535c12bd3b008a40" type:QBChatDialogTypeGroup];
updateDialog.pushOccupantsIDs = @[@"300", @"301", @"302"];
updateDialog.name = @"school friends";
 
[QBRequest updateDialog:updateDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *responce, QBChatDialog *dialog) {
 
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
 
}];
```

For more detail  check this [Update_group_dialog](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Update_group_dialog)

And for chat in group dialogue check [Chat_in_group_dialog](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Chat_in_group_dialog)

Don't forget to use delegate method.

## pragma mark QBChatDelegate

```
- (void)chatRoomDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message fromDialogId:(NSString *)dialogId{
 
}
```

**Edit 1:-** you will get DialogId with retriving all dialog.

```
QBResponsePage *page = [QBResponsePage responsePageWithLimit:100 skip:0];
 
[QBRequest dialogsForPage:page extendedRequest:nil successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *dialogObjects, NSSet *dialogsUsersIDs, QBResponsePage *page) {
 
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
 
}];
```

**Edit 2:-** To know the dialogId when creating new Dialog use **createChatNotificationForGroupChatCreation** method.

```
- (QBChatMessage *)createChatNotificationForGroupChatCreation:(QBDialog *)dialog
{
    // create message:
    QBChatMessage *inviteMessage = [QBChatMessage message];
 
    NSMutableDictionary *customParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    customParams[@"xmpp_room_jid"] = dialog.roomJID;
    customParams[@"name"] = dialog.name;
    customParams[@"_id"] = dialog.ID;
    customParams[@"type"] = @(dialog.type);
    customParams[@"occupants_ids"] = [dialog.occupantIDs componentsJoinedByString:@","];
 
    // Add notification_type=1 to extra params when you created a group chat 
    //
    customParams[@"notification_type"] = @"1";
 
    inviteMessage.customParameters = customParams;
 
    return inviteMessage;
}
```

Comment: But badal there is a scenario. I wont know whether that dialog already exists or not?

Will update dialog return me an error if it does not exists?

Comment: How would i know the dialogID? which i have ti pass in initWithDialogID

Comment: dialogID will help you .

Comment: well while creating a new one how will i find it?

Comment: I am not sure but you will get id as same when creating new dialogue.

Comment: badal, Can we chat in discussion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105531/discussion-between-badal-shah-and-kiran).